# Why doesn't C# have package private?

Tags: c#, java, package-private

I'm learning C# and coming from a Java world, I was a little confused to see that C# doesn't have a "package private". Most comments I've seen regarding this amount to "You cannot do it; the language wasn't designed this way". I also saw some workarounds that involve `internal` and `partial` along with comments that said these workarounds go against the language's design.

Why was C# designed this way? Also, how would I do something like the following: I have a `Product` class and a `ProductInstance` class. The only way I want a `ProductInstance` to be created is via a factory method in the `Product` class. In Java, I would put `ProductInstance` in the same package as `Product`, but make its constructor `package private` so that only `Product` would have access to it. This way, anyone who wants to create a `ProductInstance` can only do so via the factory method in the `Product` class. How would I accomplish the same thing in C#?

Comment: Make the Product classes constructor Private, then have a Public Static Function that returns a ProductInstance, eg: var p = Product.GetProductInstance

Comment: Looking at the answers, I see no answer to the why. I feel it is a big code smell setting a method `internal` where it is intended to be used only by a few "friendly" classes (see the `friend` keyword in C++). I don't want to break my application into hundreds of dll just to prevent smelly access, nor do I like to leave my detail implementation open (basically public to the whole dev team). Should I write giant classes with ten subclasses to overcome this limitation?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`internal` is what you are after.  It means the member is accessible by any class in the same assembly.  There is nothing wrong with using it for this purpose (Product & ProductInstance), and is one of the things for which it was designed.   C# chose not to make namespaces significant -- they are used for organization, not to determine what types can see one another, as in java with *package private*.

`partial` is nothing at all like `internal` **or** `package private`.  It is simply a way to split the implementation of a class into multiple files, with some extensibility options thrown in for good measure.

Comment: So I just need to mark `ProductInstance`'s constructor as `internal`?

Comment: @Vivin, yes, and presumably the class as well.

Comment: No, creating an assembly for just one factory class is bad advice. Having hundreds of assemblies makes a project hard to manage.

Comment: @miguel, that you have conflated my answer into advising one create a separate assembly for each class is rather surprising.

Comment: When you said "There is nothing wrong with using it for this purpose (Product & ProductInstance)" I took it to mean that you should create an assembly for this one purpose.

Comment: @miguel, I'm really confused by why you think the use of internal implies creating more assemblies.  In fact, without jumping through hoops (`[InternalsVisibleTo]`) splitting classes into separate assemblies _prohibits_ you from using `internal`.

Comment: OP's goal: The only way to create `ProductInstance` is via `Product.factory`. Your answer: use `internal`. But `internal` will still allow `ProductInstance` to be created via its constructor by other classes in the assembly. Therefore the only way your answer makes any sense is if `Product` and `ProductInstnace` are in their own assembly.

Answer (score 9):

Packages don't really exist in the same way as they do in Java. Namespaces are used to organize code and prevent naming clashes, but not for access control. Projects/assemblies can be used for access control, but you can't have nested projects/assemblies like you can with packages.

Use `internal` to hide one project's members from another.