# Package private in C#?

Tags: c#, java

In Java a method that hasn't any visibility keyword is called package private and can be seen in from objects in the same package.

If a method or a field hasn't any visibility keyword in C# is it also package private and if not whats the visibility then?

And how can I make a field package private in C#?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

by default, a class is marked as `internal` if not specified. In this case, only classes from the same assembly can use it.

*Actually, this can be overriden by using the [`InternalsVisibleToAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) which allow to autorize a specifif other assembly to see internal types*

Answer (score 4):

I think the equivalent of a package private in c# is an internal so you can see the method or attributes in the same assembly.

By default a class without access modifier specified is internal.

[Here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/puranindia/WhatareAccessModifiersinCsharp08202009024156AM/WhatareAccessModifiersinCsharp.aspx)'s a good summary

Answer (score 2):

I think that the corresponding visibility access keyword is internal. You can also declare assemblies and mark internal members as accesible for them.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tke9fxk(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 2):

In C#, the default access for methods and fields is private.

C# does not have Java's "package-private", but internal is close; use keyword *internal*

[See this article](http://csharpfeeds.com/post.aspx?id=6962)  and this [StackOverflow item.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964887/why-doesnt-c-have-package-private?tab=oldest)

Answer (score 0):

By default, a class member is private. The class itself is by default package private.
Package private is called "internal"

Comment: this is wrong. internal and package-private is not the same thing. internal is assembly-private, not package-private.